# Technecium and Technetium

Tags: elements

Was technecium "recently" renamed technetium in English? I know when I formally studied chemistry (in the USA) that earth, air, water and fire were on the periodic table, but I really remember the element as being technecium.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After German chemists claimed to have discovered element 43 in 1925, the name *masurium* was used in the first publications. However, the German experiments could not be reproduced.

The official discovery of element 43 was accomplished by C. Perrier and E. Segrè in 1936. They proposed the name *technetium* (see [Perrier, C.; Segrè, E. Technetium : The Element of Atomic Number 43, *Nature,* **1947,** *159,* 24.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/159024a0)).

In 1949, the 15th IUPAC Conference adopted this name.

The name *technetium* was also used in the early American literature, for example in *Radioactivity Applied to Chemistry;* Wahl, A. C., Bonner, N. A., Eds.; John Wiley & Sons: New York, 1951.

Comment: There are plenty of English publications where it is spelled "technecium" https://books.google.com/books?id=J6k4-N5lPX8C&pg=PA275&dq=%22technecium%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLj7WequjLAhVIRyYKHZpRAkgQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22technecium%22&f=false It's either a common misspelling or an alternative spelling.

Comment: And may with "Technicium" https://books.google.com/books?id=WuFFAAAAYAAJ&q=%22Technicium%22&dq=%22Technicium%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7_d6irOjLAhXCMSYKHZUwAYoQ6AEIJjAC https://books.google.com/books?id=8ztrAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Technicium%22&dq=%22Technicium%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7_d6irOjLAhXCMSYKHZUwAYoQ6AEIQzAI

Comment: LOL - That "early American literature" was what I cut my teeth on. My first high school chemistry class was in 1967.

Answer (score 2):

It's always been **technetium** in English.

In fact, I can't find an English entry for **technecium** on the internet at all.  I'd venture to guess you're Czech based on the search results, which did yield other language pages.

Comment: No, I'm American not Czech.

Comment: Here is a black swan, one of many actually...  https://books.google.com/books?id=dQ0neMLQNskC&pg=PA1194&dq=%22technecium%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXr9-y85HPAhVE7SYKHetkClMQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=%22technecium%22&f=false